# Conda is not activated when runing a non-interactive shell in a docker container

Tags: bash, docker, shell, conda

Let me first present you my setup and at the end - my problem.

I download and install *mambaforge* in my *Dockerfile*, then I build an env `myenv` (all as root with `RUN` instructions).
What is relevant is the following sections:

*Dockerfile*

```
##### SETUP ENTRYPOINT #####
COPY entrypoint.sh /bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN /bin/bash -c "chmod +x /bin/entrypoint.sh \
  && groupadd conda \
  && chgrp -R conda /mambaforge \
  && chmod 770 -R /mambaforge"
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

*entrypoint.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
ID=9001
useradd --shell /bin/bash -u $ID -o -c "" -m user
export HOME=/home/user
adduser user conda &> /dev/null
/usr/sbin/gosu user /bin/bash -c "/mambaforge/bin/conda init bash &> /dev/null"
echo "conda activate myenv" >> ${HOME}/.bashrc
exec /usr/sbin/gosu user "$@"
```

The logic is that I create a new group `conda`, give it permissions to the mambaforge installation directory and then (in the entrypoint script) I create a new user, add it to the group, initialise `conda` for him (that is `.bashrc` modification) and also append automatic activation of `myenv` environment to the rcfile too. Finally, I run what was left as the container command `CMD` as that user with `gosu`. The idea was to execute as non-root.

This all works file with:

```
$ docker run --name project -it project
(myenv) user@bcdf6d7e29c4:$
```

In the interactive mode, as expected, I am the `user` and I already activated `myenv`.

However, this does not work in non-interactive mode.
One of the tools in `myenv` is `make`.

```
$ docker run --name project project /bin/bash -c "source /home/user/.bashrc; make"
/bin/bash: line 1: make: command not found
```

What is going on? How do I correct it so that the 2nd command works too?

Comment: I find it weird, that you use a **non-interactive** shell script `entrypoint.sh` to modify a configuration file for an **interactive** shell (.bashrc). Moreover, every time you run entrypoint.sh, the .bashrc will get the same line added  over and over again. I have no idea what you are doing here, and also don't know conda, but this simply does not look right. If you **really** need your .bashrc be initialized to a certain well defined state, create a `.bashrc.master` using your text editor, and in your entrypoint.sh do a `cp ~/.bashrc.master ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: BTW, consider the use of the `BASH_ENV` environment variable to process on startup of a non-interactive `bash` a configuration file which contains your _conda_ settings (or whatever you need). See [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-environment-variables)  how to set environment variables with docker.

Comment: It seems like you might want to do most of this setup in the Dockerfile; use the `USER` directive there to select the non-root user; don't try to set up `.bashrc`; and reduce the entrypoint script to just `conda activate myenv && exec "$@"`.  That would be a little more efficient and closer to standard Docker practice.  It's not obvious to my why what you show wouldn't work, though.

Comment: @DavidMaze: I don't want to use `USER` as in reality I am also mounting a volume and need to match uid/gid to avoid file permission issues (https://denibertovic.com/posts/handling-permissions-with-docker-volumes/) What I posted above is a simplified example of my problem, I need to delegate all the user-related stuff to the entrypoint for the volume stuff to work.
Many thanks!

Comment: In what you've shown, the ownership of `/mambaforge` doesn't seem to be an issue, and the only thing that seems to specifically depend on the current user ID is trying to write to its home directory (and IME "home directory" and "shell dotfiles" aren't normal Docker concepts).  You can declare a default `USER` and override it with a `docker run -u` option at runtime or similar.

Comment: @DavidMaze : the example above is simplified, the problem is not with `/mamgaforge` but with another external dir I mount as a volume from the host machine, lets say: `/mounted`. without `gosu` I run into troubles like in the URL I mentioned in the comment above. Therefore I need to create the user with a proper ID (matching the host UID) at the level of entrypoint; at the time of image build I cannot know what UID to assign yet.